# Equal distribution based on multiple criteria algorithm

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, algorithm, entity-framework

Let's say I have a database table that stores `News` records. Each `News` records will have a `Category` property. I would like to retrieve multiple `News` records and have an equal distribution of `Category` properties.

For Example,
If I would like to retrieve 9 `News` records, it would be ideal for me to retrieve 3 Entertainment News, 3 Sports News and 3 Politic News. So far, I've just only created a special class to carry out this algorithm:

```
public class NewsFetcher(Applicationdbcontext db){
   //implementation...
}
```

Is there any recommended algorithm to do so?

**EDIT**

I am using `Entity Framework` for this application. The following is the `model` class for `News`:

```
public class News{
   public int id {get;set;}
   public string Category {get;set;}
   public string Content {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `Category` field in News table ?

Comment: Are you asking how to do it using Entity Framework? SQL?

Comment: @Null, Yeah I will have a ``Category`` field in News table..
@alekkowalczyk, I'm asking how to do it using Entity Framework, Sorry if my post wasn't that clear, I will edit it now.

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish this and how did it fail to meet your goals?

Comment: I don't think this is about Entity Framework. The simple solution is to do 3 queries, one for each category, returning only the first 9/3 = 3 results. If the number of categories and the number of news for each category changes, change the limit accordingly. With EF, you use the `Take` linq method to pass on the number of records to be returned.